# How does one create a dictionary from a data-frame with a multi-index column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

How can I create a dictionary from the following df? Trying to use the `to_dict` method but not having much luck.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,90,80,70,36,45], [101,78,65,88,55,78], [92,77,42,79,43,32], [103,98,76,54,45,65]], index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01' ,periods=4))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("mkf", "Open"), ("mkf", "Close"), ("tdf", "Open"), ("tdf","Close"), ("ghi","Open"), ("ghi", "Close")))
df
            mkf        tdf        ghi
           Open Close Open Close Open Close
2022-01-01  100    90   80    70   36    45
2022-01-02  101    78   65    88   55    78
2022-01-03   92    77   42    79   43    32
2022-01-04  103    98   76    54   45    65
```

The desired outcome is a dictionary where the keys are `mkf`, `tdf`, `ghi` and the values would be the contents of the sub data frames:

```
{'mkf' : 
                Open Close
    2022-01-01  100    90   
    2022-01-02  101    78   
    2022-01-03   92    77   
    2022-01-04  103    98,
'tdf' :         Open Close
    2022-01-01  80    70
    2022-01-02  65    88
    2022-01-03  42    79
    2022-01-04  76    54,
'ghi':
                Open Close
    2022-01-01   36    45
    2022-01-02   55    78
    2022-01-03   43    32
    2022-01-04   45    65 
}
```

Comment: what's the expected outcome? it's not clear what it is from your post

Comment: @enke I updated the post to reflect desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
dct = {c: df[c] for c in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()}
```

Output:

```
{'mkf':             Open  Close
 2022-01-01   100     90
 2022-01-02   101     78
 2022-01-03    92     77
 2022-01-04   103     98,
 'tdf':             Open  Close
 2022-01-01    80     70
 2022-01-02    65     88
 2022-01-03    42     79
 2022-01-04    76     54,
 'ghi':             Open  Close
 2022-01-01    36     45
 2022-01-02    55     78
 2022-01-03    43     32
 2022-01-04    45     65}
```

Comment: in principal yes.  But is there a way to produce the output such that the values are blocks of data without the meta data i.e. like a dataframe?

Comment: Ah I see, so each value of `mkf`, `tdf`, etc., is actually a dataframe?

Comment: Check now, @jgg.